# T-SQL Trigger Results in Blocking

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, locking, blocking

Help! The following trigger results in blocking once executed:

```
USE [Automation]
GO
/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[AfterInsertSendEmail]    Script Date: 08/06/2012 22:05:54 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      Chris Cannon
-- Create date: 20120806
-- Description: TBC
-- =============================================
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[AfterInsertSendEmail] 
   ON  [dbo].[Enquiry] 
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN;
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for trigger here
    DECLARE @l_profile_name nvarchar(128) = 'Automation Enquiries';
    DECLARE @l_importance varchar(6) = 'High';
    DECLARE @l_sensitivity varchar(12) = 'Personal';
    DECLARE @l_recipients varchar(500) = 'a.n.other@somewhere.co.uk';
    DECLARE @l_copy_recipients varchar(500) = 'b.n.other@somewhere.co.uk';
    DECLARE @l_blind_copy_recipients varchar(500) = 'c.n.other@somewhere.co.uk';
    DECLARE @l_reply_to varchar(500) = (SELECT [EmailAddress] FROM [inserted]);
    DECLARE @l_subject nvarchar(255) = (SELECT 'New Enquiry From ' + [FirstName] + ' ' + [LastName] FROM [inserted]);
    DECLARE @l_body nvarchar(500) = 'TBC';
    DECLARE @l_query nvarchar(500) = 'SELECT TOP(1) * FROM [Automation].[dbo].[Enquiry] ORDER BY [Id] DESC';
    DECLARE @l_query_result_separator char(1) = CHAR(9);
    DECLARE @l_query_result_no_padding bit = 1;
    DECLARE @l_attach_query_result_as_file bit = 1;
    DECLARE @l_query_attachment_filename nvarchar(260) = (SELECT 'automation_enquiry_' + REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(CONVERT(nvarchar(19), [DateSubmitted], 120), '-', ''), ' ', ''), ':', '') + '.csv' FROM [inserted]);
    DECLARE @l_append_query_error bit = 1;

    EXEC [msdb].[dbo].[sp_send_dbmail]
          @profile_name = @l_profile_name
        , @importance = @l_importance
        , @sensitivity = @l_sensitivity
        , @recipients = @l_recipients
        , @copy_recipients = @l_copy_recipients
        , @blind_copy_recipients = @l_blind_copy_recipients
        , @reply_to = @l_reply_to
        , @subject = @l_subject
        , @body = @l_body
        , @query = @l_query
        , @query_result_separator = @l_query_result_separator
        , @query_result_no_padding = @l_query_result_no_padding
        , @attach_query_result_as_file = @l_attach_query_result_as_file
        , @query_attachment_filename = @l_query_attachment_filename
        , @append_query_error = @l_append_query_error;

END;
```

From what I can tell it looks like this line:

```
DECLARE @l_query nvarchar(500) = 'SELECT TOP(1) * FROM [Automation].[dbo].[Enquiry] ORDER BY [Id] DESC';
```

maybe blocking something or the trigger itself blocks that statement.

I've tried several things which no luck.

Please help!

Comment: `inserted` and `deleted` are tables so that they can represent the results of set operations.  Designing a trigger on the assumption that they will always contain exactly one row is generally a bad plan.

Comment: @HABO but if I know that only one row will be inserted at a time then I shouldn't have to worry?

Comment: The statement the declares `@l_query` simply assigns a string literal.  It can't block.  One of the `SELECT` statements could.

Comment: If I had a Quatloo for everyone who was certain that there would never be more than one row affected, I would be riding around Mars on a dune buggy now.  If it doesn't bite you, it's still a maintenance disaster.  Since there could _never_ be more than one row inserted, add an ASSERT: `if ( select count(42) from inserted ) > 1 then RaIsError( '[AfterInsertSendEmail] Chris promised not to do this.', 13, 0 )`.  (Love that Sun God boo-boo.)

Comment: The only query on `Enquiry` is being passed via `@l_query`.  You could create the value for `@l_query` so that it returns literal values that you have extracted from `inserted`: `select 42 as EnquiryId, 'UncleBob' as UserName, ...`.  No `from` needed, no chance to block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wel you are in the middle of a transaction so at least that row is locked, then you send a mail, the mail is running a select top on the same table which you have a lock on...

You could try nolock as losbear suggested, however seeing as the query you ae running is presumably meant to show the details of the record you've just inserted and you have inserted availble in your trigger, why bother with @query at all.

Personally I've never liked the idea of sending a mail in the middle of my transaction. I'd rather queue the request, commit the transaction and then have some "service" do the mailing. That would be a fair bit more work though.

Comment: Thank you for your clear response. Re. queuing - my understanding is that sp_send_dbmail does queue emails. What do you mean why bother with @query? It is needed to generate the attachment for the email.

Comment: Mispoke, I meant build a query of Literals e.g. Select 'Fred' as Name, etc. sendmail queues emails, it does not queue generating them. So you have an email_queue table, trigger an insert to it, then an other process that used sendmail to queue an email from it. It was a useful when xp_sendmail was all that was available, as problems with your mail server failed the database transaction.

Comment: The literal string is a good idea, but it's too much work, besides this is one of the very few times I get to use `SELECT *` without worrying - wouldn't want to miss out on that.

Answer (score 1):

try using "WITH (NOLOCK)"

```
SELECT TOP(1) * FROM [Automation].[dbo].[Enquiry] WITH (NOLOCK) ORDER BY [Id] DESC
```